# How to change this ruby match line to return true or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so my ruby is rusty. I have a line that looks for a match...

```
self.volunteer_event.description.match(/^Roster #/)
```

gives me this...

```
[1] pry(#<VolunteerShift>)> self.volunteer_event.description.match(/^Roster #/)
=> #<MatchData "Roster #">
```

I want to change it to give me "true" if it has a match or "false" for no

What simple ruby incantation can I use to achieve this?

Comment: There are many useful methods you can use when you have a [`MatchData`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/MatchData.html). Of course you don't have to use `.match`, but could also use the `=~` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Regexp docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html), I see [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F) and [`match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-match). Use `match?` which returns a boolean. Functions that return a boolean often end with `?` in Ruby.

Comment: lol....yep....just found that....I was about to delete this post...but maybe I'll keep it to help the next person.

Comment: @thefonso Thanks for undeleting. I'm new to ruby, and find answering questions like this a good learning opportunity.

Comment: To support Ruby versions prior to v2.4, when `String#match?`made it debut, you could write `!!self.volunteer_event.description.match(/^Roster #/)`. Recall `String#match` returns `nil` if and only if there is no match. `!!x` is the same as `!(!x)`, so if `x` is falsy (`nil` or `false`) `!x #=> true` and therefore `!(!x) #=> !(true) #=> false`; if `x` is truthy (not falsy), `!x #=> false`, and therefore `!(!x) #=> !(false) #=> true`. Putting `!!` at the beginning of an expression to have it return `true` or `false` is an old trick my grampa taught me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This seems like it should be a separate answer, not a comment.

Comment: Actually, I'm not fond of `!!` (a bit too clever) as one generally can use the result of `match` (truthy or `nil`) directly, as in an `if` statement, but I thought `!!` was worth mentioning for the benefit of readers who haven't seen it. `match?` is so much better, in part because it reads better.

Comment: Alternatively `!str.match(/.../).nil?` or `!(str !~ /.../)` for older rubies.